# wd tv live streaming media player

Tags: 12.04

I just recently bought the WD TV Live streaming media player. I called there customer support center and they could not help me. Its a box that plugs into my TV by an hdmi cable. It walks you through there set-up menus. What is supposed to happen next is your supposed to share media,video,and picture files thru your TV. Problem is I get get the system to even recognize my home computer.I was hoping someone had some insight on my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to share the media from the device** to your computer you can
   install XBMC, then add a video source from upnp device.

**If you want to share the media from your PC** with ubuntu to this device
   you need to install a streaming server, i use [minidlna](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Minidlna) is very
   easy and ligh but there are [another options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/streaming_media).

```
sudo apt-get install minidlna 
sudo gedit /etc/minidlna.conf
```

add the folders to share for example

```
media_dir=I,/home/user/Images
media_dir=V,/home/user/Videos
media_dir=M,/home/user/Music
```

uncomment this lines in the configuration file

```
db_dir=/var/lib/minidlna
log_dir=/var/log
```

refresh the database

```
sudo minidlna -R
```

restart the service

```
sudo service minidlna restart
```

And then you should see the name of you computer in the device.